# How to convert the unit like Dozen to Pcs in vb.net

Tags: vb.net-2010

How do I convert the Unit in vb.net like below sample.

```
12 Pcs=1 Dozen
```

If I Put 14 Pcs into textbox1.text it will reply in a label box like below. Please help me.

```
14 Pcs- Textbox1.Text

1 Dozen 2 Pcs- Label1.text
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
        Dim Quantity As Integer
        Dim Dozens As Integer
        Dim Pcs As Integer

        Int32.TryParse(txtPcs.Text, Quantity)

        Dozens = Quantity / 12

        Pcs = (Quantity - (Dozens * 12)) Mod 12
```

Comment: i did not understand, where i input the value which will convert into dosens & Pcs.. Please Make the code as per the given format..           textbox1.text= 14 (Input)   Label1.text= 1 Dozen 2 Pcs (Output)